# Using set operators in domain odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

I have a entity "pay_activity" with an antivity (activity_id) and a purchase (purchase_id).
The activity has a list of bills and purchase has a list of bills as well. I want to apply a domain to activity, so the user can only select an activity that has 
at least one bill in the list of bills of the purchase. I have tried:

```
set (activity_id.bills_ids) & set (purchase_bill_id) != None.
```

But I cannot apply those operators to the domain. is there any way to select only an activity that has at least one bill in the list purchase_bill_id?

```
class CenterPayActivity(models.Model):

    _name = 'center.pay_activity'
    _description = 'Permite distribuir los pagos entre las actividades'

    activity_id = fields.Many2one('center.activity', string='Actividad', required=True )

    purchase_id = fields.Many2one('center.purchase', related="payment_id.bill_ids")

    purchase_bill_id = fields.Many2many('center.bill', related="purchase_id.bill_ids")


class CenterActivity(models.Model):

    _name = 'center.activity'

    bills_ids = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='center.bill',
                                  delete="cascade",
                                  compute="_compute_bills_ids")
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-stored field `center.activity.bills_ids` [cannot be searched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61894841/domain-for-many2one-field-not-working-in-odoo/61901358#61901358). To use it in the `activity_id` field domain you should set the `store` attribute to `True` or define the `search` method.

`purchase_id` is a Many2one field related to a Many2many field, I think you should remove the related attribute.

Try to:

- Set `center.activity.bills_ids` store attribute to True.
- Remove `related attribute` from  `center.pay_activity.purchase_id`.
- Use the followig domain in the form view:

  ```
  domain="[('bills_ids', 'in', purchase_bill_id)]"
  ```